# glyphs appearing outside of plotting region with SVG output backend in bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I recently upgraded bokeh from 0.12.4 to 0.12.10, primarily to enable `Plot.output.backend = "svg"` for the SaveTool. This feature works pretty well, but I've been experiencing other plotting issues when it is enabled.

I have a layout based plot composed of 2 subplots and a slider panel, but the issue seems to be plot- and glyph-independent. For example, the first plot in the layout is based on:

```
p1=figure(width=1500, x_range=get_xrange(rawdat), tools="box_zoom,tap,xwheel_zoom,reset,save", y_range=get_yrange(rawdat))
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(ps=rawdat.ps, logsp=-log10(rawdat.p_score), radii=rawdat.radii, alpha=rawdat.alpha, color=rawdat.color, mafcolor=rawdat.mafcolor, weightcolor=rawdat.weightcolor, outcol=rawdat.outcolor, outalpha=rawdat.outalpha, alpha_prevsig=rawdat.alpha_prevsig, snpid=rawdat.rs, rs=rawdat.ensembl_rs, maf=rawdat.maf, csq=rawdat.ensembl_consequence))

p1.circle(x='ps', y='logsp', radius='radii', fill_alpha='alpha', fill_color='color', line_color='outcol', line_alpha='outalpha', line_width=6, radius_units='screen', source=source)
```

When `Plot.output.backend = "svg"` is enabled, glyphs overflow outside of the plotting region (especially when zooming), so much so that my circles collide with the bokeh toolbar, as below:
[image: example]

This behaviour happens no matter what the glyphs are (on plot 2, segments and rectangles do the same). When the backend is set to the default, the plot does not overflow. This happens on Opera, Vivaldi, Safari and Firefox.

I'd like to see if other people have experienced and/or solved this before I raise an issue on their github page.

Comment: I'm seeing this too after recently updating to bokeh 0.12.13, but with the `webgl` backend